# CSS not reflected in localhost page after -build, -serve, using Jekyll and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I have been following the tutorial here -> https://www.andrewmunsell.com/tutorials/jekyll-by-example/tutorial to build my first site learning both Jekyll and Bootstrap. I am new to CSS, and a beginner with HTML.

I am on the step that begins with the bold subject line "Liquid Template System".

The problem is my site is not reflecting the CSS.

In the tutorial code, he references , however in the Bootstrap-3.2.0-dist from www.getbootstrap.com, there is no longer a bootstrap-responsive.css. There are only the following:

- bootstrap-theme.css
- bootstrap-theme.min.css
- bootstrap.min.css
- bootstrap.css

My code is below; which I have cycled through referencing all four css files listed and they aren't reflected when I jekyll build then jekyll serve. Currently I am only local hosting during this development, once finished I will push to my site. I have the css directory in my _site directory, which is also where my index.html file is located.

Any one have an experience with Jekyll not reflecting CSS changes in Bootstrap?

Based on other searches on StackOverflow, I have tried clearing my cache, rebuilding and serving with no joy. Advice is appreciated here. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>{{ site.name }}</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="{{ site.description }}">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="brand" href="#">{{ site.name }}</a>
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

 {{ content }}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP was referring to Bootstrap **2**. The latest version, **3**, does not have a separate file for responsive elements, because it *assumes responsiveness from the off*. If you just want to follow along with the tutorial then you can download [Bootstrap 2 here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/).

Further:

> I have the css directory in my _site directory, which is also where my index.html file is located.

Is your `_site` directory the ServerRoot for your `localhost`? If not, drop the initial forward slash from the `link` attribute, as it's currently pointing to your ServerRoot.

Comment: Thank you Ian for the simple solution - I've spent about at least 10 hours trying to put a round peg in a square hole as they say.

Comment: Any time, hopefully they're lining up now. BTW, if you found this answer useful, please mark it as the correct answer to your question. This allows other would-be answerers to notice that a solution has been reached, and also gives the helper some satisfaction from doing so! Welcome to Stack Overflow :) - finally, consider looking at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'd summarise by saying that brevity is good :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, welcome, and link. Done and done. Have a good one.